# How to get the row with the max value of one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get the row with the max `testid` (where `studyid` equals 6) from the table which looks like

```
 seq | studyid  | buildnumber |  testid |
 1   |    6     |   1904      |    1    |
 2   |    6     |   1904      |    1    | 
 3   |    6     |   1904      |    1    | 
 4   |    6     |   1029      |    3    | 
 5   |    6     |   1029      |    3    | 
 6   |    6     |   1104      |    5    | 
 7   |    6     |   1104      |    5    | 
 8   |    6     |   3049      |    4    | 
 9   |    6     |   3049      |    4    | 
10   |    7     |   4029      |    11   | 
11   |    8     |   5049      |    21   | 
12   |    9     |   6049      |    14   | 
13   |   10     |   7049      |    54   | 
14   |   11     |   8049      |    13   |
```

the expected result would be

```
6   |    6     |   1104    |    5    |
```

and my query I am trying is

```
select max(buildnumber) buildnumber, max(testid) testid, studyid 
from testdata 
where studyid = 6
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What part of your "expected result" is a max? 1104 is not the maximum buildnumber.

Comment: @PatrickQ . . . The `testid` is max.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ah, I didn't note that in the query. Good edit Strawberry, that makes it a lot clearer.

Comment: @Kyungmo why should it return the `6 6 1104 5` and not the `7 6 1104 5` row?

Comment: @PatrickQ Well, it makes it a *bit* clearer. Still room for improvement though! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the logic you want (the biggest `testid` for `studyid = 6`, then use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from testdata t
where studyid = 6
order by testid desc
limit 1;
```

Note this could return either row 6 or 7.  The question is phrased as "get the row with the max testid . . .", implying that there is only one such row.  However, the sample data has two such rows, with no explanation of how to choose one over the other.

Comment: @YellowBird . . . It will be the rows with id 6 or 7.  Can you explain your comment?

Comment: @YellowBird . . . Of course it is.  It is the max of `testid`.  If I hadn't seen this, I wouldn't have answered.  Note the answer starts with this understanding of the question (and I would welcome the OP to comment on that).

Comment: I'm not sure, but this answer might not _guarantee_ that the row with seq = 6 (which is given as part of the desired result) is selected since there are two rows with the same `testid`.

Answer (score 1):

Use order by to get your target row first, then use  llomit:

```
select *
from testdata
where studyid = 6
order by testid desc, seq
limit 1
```

Although not stated, your sample data suggests that ties for yhe msx testid should be broken using the lowest seq, hence having seq in the order by clause.